Problem building NextJS app using Material UI
Whenever I try to build my app I end up getting the following error

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

Should a page import any Material UI elements?
Even the following code results in the error
import { Box } from "@mui/material";

export default function Page() {
    return (
        <Box >
            
        </Box>
    )
}

However when I remove the import statement and replace <Box> with <div> it works fine.
I already tried to import without curly brackets, but that also didn't work
I looked this error up and the common consensus seems to be something is wrong with the export / import and since I can't modify what's exported by Material UI there isn't much I can do

Have you tried import Box from @mui/material/Box; as described here
